# How to reproduce these images with Tikz/ pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm completely new to latex and Tikz, and I'm trying to reproduce these two images:

[image]

Here's all I've got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

Words

\section{section name here}
Words

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (6,0) arc [radius=5, start angle=120, end angle= 90];<br>
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption 1 here}
\end{figure}

More words
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (2,0); 
\draw (3.5,0.5) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption 2 here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure how to get the dots on the lines, the curved arrows, or the letters in there, though.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), complete with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` and the packages you loaded in your preamble.

Comment: Why don't you read [this](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf)? It's absolutely fantastic to learn fast. I've read tons of manuals without fully understanding what I was doing and so, but this...I guarantee that you'll learn in less than 1 hour all you need to do the 80%-90% of what you'll need in typesetting simple images like the one you posted. It would be much more problematic and less clear to explain it here. You don't need to read all the file I linked you, just the first few tutorials. Enjoy! And then if you'll need additional help we're here :D

Comment: @PierPaolo Like that?

Comment: Almost! `;)` Next time you can leave unused packages out and include just the `tikzpicture` environment in the `document` environment and you're good to go. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

This should help you to get started. I used mostly the `decorations.markings` library for positioning. You may want to check section 48.5 of the mighty PGF manual for more info.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\tiny\itshape},decoration={markings, 
  mark=between positions .1 and .9 step 8mm with {\draw[fill=white](0,0) circle (1pt);},
  mark=at position .1 with {\node[yshift=-3pt]{x};},
  mark=at position .41 with {\node[yshift=-4pt]{y};},
  mark=at position .71 with {\node[yshift=-3pt]{z};},
  mark=between positions .39 and .9 step 8mm with {\arrow{stealth}},
  mark=at position .2 with {\node[yshift=5pt]{s};},
  mark=at position .5 with {\node[yshift=5pt]{t};}
}]
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (6,0) arc [radius=5, start angle=120, end angle= 90];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\tiny\itshape}]
\draw [postaction=decorate,-stealth,decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position .05 with {\node[font=\bfseries\small,yshift=-5pt]{R};},
  mark=at position .2 with {\draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (1pt);},
  mark=at position .8 with {\draw[fill=white](0,0) circle (1pt);},
  mark=at position .95 with {\node[yshift=-4pt]{t};}}, 
] (0,0) -- (2,0); 
\draw[-stealth] (1,.5)  to[bend left=30] (2.2,1.1) node[xshift=-.8cm]{$\phi$};
\draw (3.5,0.5) circle [radius=1];
\draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position .2 with {\draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (1pt);},
  mark=at position .2 with {\node[xshift=-4pt]{x};},
  mark=at position .8 with {\draw[fill=white](0,0) circle (1pt);},
  mark=at position .8 with {\node[yshift=4pt]{$g^{t}x$};}}
] (2.8,.5)  to[bend left=30] (3.7,1);
\node[font=\scriptsize\itshape] at(4,-.1){M};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to dcmst's one, but uses more styling, so the picture itself has less code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  >=latex,
  every to/.style={bend left},
  every point/.style = {circle, inner sep={.75\pgflinewidth}, opacity=1, draw, solid, fill=white},
  point/.style={insert path={node[every point, #1]{}}},
  at/.style 2 args = {
    decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {#2}},
    postaction={decorate}
  },
  pt at/.style args={#1"#2"#3}{at={#1}{\node[point=#3,above]{#2};}},
  arrpt at/.style args={#1"#2"}{at={#1}{\arrow{>}\node[point,below right]{#2};}}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[pt at=.2""black, pt at=.7"", ->]
      (0,0) node[below]{$\mathbb{R}$} -- (1.5,0) node[below]{$t$};
    \draw (4,1) circle (1.5cm) node[below right=5mm]{$M$};
    \draw[->] (.5,.5) to node[above]{$\varphi$}(2.2,1.5);
    \draw[pt at=.3"$x$"black,pt at=.7"$g_t{x}$"] (3,1) to (5,1.5);
    \draw[arrpt at=.2"$x$",arrpt at=.5"$y$",arrpt at=.8"$z$"] (0,2) to (3,4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]